# Not able to connect to metastore using Thrift URI - Hive

Tags: hive, apache-pig

Can someone please help me with below issue, I have added thrift uri value in hive-site.xml. Aslo how can i verify the correct uri value?

I am running this command

```
grunt> battingdata = LOAD 'default.batting' USING  org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
```

and getting below error

> 2015-09-29 02:42:36,937 [main] WARN  hive.metastore - Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...

Thanks for your help in advance.